# I am getting problem while rendering Kannada text font Tunga using PdfSharp package to pdf from ASP.NET Web API C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, fonts, pdf-generation, pdfsharp

As I have mentioned in the question, I am trying to print Kannada text one of the Indian language which is supported by Tunga font but I could not able to print it properly in PDF. I am using PdfSharp NugetPackage.

Here is my code

```
XFont nudifont = new XFont("Tunga", 10, XFontStyle.Bold, options);
graph.DrawImage(image, new XRect(200, 50, 200, 150)); // Adjust coordinates as needed
graph.DrawString("ಕರ್ನಾಟಕ ಸರ್ಕಾರ", nudifont, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 230, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopCenter);
graph.DrawString("GOVERNMENT OF KARNATAKA", fontone, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 290, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopCenter);
graph.DrawString("ಕರ್ನಾಟಕ ರಾಜ್ಯ ಲೆಕ್ಕ ಪರಿಶೋಧನೆ ಮತ್ತು ಲೆಕ್ಕ ಪತ್ರ ಇಲಾಖೆ", nudifont, XBrushes.Black, new XRect(0, 350, pdfPage.Width.Point, pdfPage.Height.Point), XStringFormats.TopCenter);
```

How I am getting the text in pdf is:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1lK3.png)

When I copy paste text from pdf to som other platform like browser or Word text is coming correctly.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you

I tried PdfSharp nuget package. I'm expecting the text to display properly in the PDF.